# One hour difference in DST

Tags: java, time, dst

I am trying to find out the day light saving start time in US which is 14th March 2021 at 2:00 AM but my code is returning the 14th March 2021 at 3:00 AM. I am not able to understand this one hour time difference. My code is listed below:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.time.zone.ZoneOffsetTransition;
import java.time.zone.ZoneRules; 
class DST{
public static void main(String[] args) {       
     ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
     ZoneRules rules = zoneId.getRules();
     ZoneOffsetTransition nextTransition = rules.nextTransition(Instant.now());
     Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(nextTransition.getInstant().atZone(zoneId).toLocalDateTime());
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a");
     String date = sdf.format(ts);
     system.out.println("DST time:"+ date );
    }
}
```

The date value is come as `March 14, 2021 at 3:00 AM` but it should be `March 14, 2021 at 2:00 AM`. I am not able to understand the difference of one hour time difference?

Comment: not sure, but have you tried printing the `ZonedDateTime` returned by `getInstant().atZone(zoneId)` instead of converting it to the `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: @Hulk: It returns `2021-03-14T03:00-04:00[America/New_York]`

Comment: Why are you mixing the old date and time API and the newer one available in the `java.time` package?

Comment: But when the transition happens at 2 AM, it means the clock is turned forward to 3, so it *IS* 3 AM at that point in time. You are getting the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

I think the (unnecessary) conversion to Timestamp is the cause of the error:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.zone.ZoneOffsetTransition;
import java.time.zone.ZoneRules;

public class DST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        ZoneRules rules = zoneId.getRules();
        ZoneOffsetTransition nextTransition = rules.nextTransition(Instant.now());
        DateTimeFormatter sdf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a");
        System.out.println("DST time:" + nextTransition.getDateTimeBefore().format(sdf));
    }
}
```

gives you (as expected):
`March 14, 2021 at 2:00 AM`

At this moment in time the time change already occurred, so it's indeed 3AM. That's the reason why API designers had to create the method `getDateTimeBefore()`.

Comment: Thanks @Benoit, problem was that I was using `nextTransition.getInstant().atZone(zoneId).toLocalDateTime()` but you are using `nextTransition.getDateTimeBefore()` not sure the difference into both? do you have any idea?

Comment: `nextTransition.getDateTimeBefore()` gives the `LocalDateTime`, not `ZondeDateTime`.

Comment: @SumitSood The problem comes from the use of `TimeStamp` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes, not from `nextTransition.getInstant()`.

Comment: @Benoit: I am trying to understand why `nextTransition.getInstant().atZone(zoneId).format(sdf) ` returns  `March 14, 2021 at 3:00 AM`

Comment: @SumitSood OK, I get it. Well at this moment in time, the time change already occurred, so it's indeed 3AM. That's the reason why API designers had to create this method `getDateTimeBefore()`.

Comment: It’s certainly `getDateTimeBefore()` making the difference. If you wanted the time before the transition, you should not be very surprised that a method thus named gives it to you.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following information from https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york

```
14 Mar 2021 - Daylight Saving Time Starts
When local standard time is about to reach
Sunday, 14 March 2021, 02:00:00 clocks are turned forward 1 hour to
Sunday, 14 March 2021, 03:00:00 local daylight time instead.
```

The information matches with the output of the following code:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.time.zone.ZoneOffsetTransition;
import java.time.zone.ZoneRules;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

        ZoneRules rules = zoneId.getRules();
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
        ZoneOffsetTransition nextTransition = rules.nextTransition(zdt.toInstant());

        ZonedDateTime zdtAfterTransition = nextTransition.getInstant().atZone(zoneId);
        ZonedDateTime zdtBeforeTransition = nextTransition.getInstant().minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).atZone(zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdtBeforeTransition);
        System.out.println(zdtAfterTransition);

        LocalDateTime ldtBeforeTransition = nextTransition.getDateTimeBefore();
        System.out.println(ldtBeforeTransition);

        // Convert LocalDateTime to java.sql.Timestamp
        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(Date.from(ldtBeforeTransition.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)).getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a");
        String date = sdf.format(ts);
        System.out.println("DST time:" + date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-13T02:00-05:00[America/New_York]
2021-03-14T03:00-04:00[America/New_York]
2021-03-14T02:00
DST time:March 14, 2021 at 2:00 am
```

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. The class, `java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date` and therefore it inherits the same problems. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.